# How to search string in files recursively in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find all log files in my `C:\` and then in these log file find a string. If the string is found the output should be the abs path of the log file where the string is found. below is what I have done till now.

```
import os
rootdir=('C:\\')
for folder,dirs,file in os.walk(rootdir):
    for files in file:
        if files.endswith('.log'):
            fullpath=open(os.path.join(folder,files),'r')
            for line in fullpath.read():
                if "saurabh" in line:
                    print(os.path.join(folder,files))
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? why you want a recursive solution?

Comment: I am not getting the output as abs path for the file which contains the 'saurabh'. for code purpose I have added 'saurabh' in one of the file

Answer (score 10):

Your code is broken at:

```
for line in fullpath.read():
```

The statement `fullpath.read()` will return the entire file as one string, and when you iterate over it, you will be iterating a character at a time.  You will never find the string 'saurabh' in a single character.

A file is its own iterator for lines, so just replace this statement with:

```
for line in fullpath:
```

Also, for cleanliness, you might want to close the file when you're done, either explicitly or by using a `with` statement.

Finally, you may want to break when you find a file, rather than printing the same file out multiple times (if there are multiple occurrences of your string):

```
import os
rootdir=('C:\\')
for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):
            fullpath = os.path.join(folder, file)
            with open(fullpath, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    if "saurabh" in line:
                        print(fullpath)
                        break
```

Comment: Great... That solved my issue. Got my mistake. Thanks a ton